Journaya Script Integration in Elementor Form Wordpress
I have integerated Journaya script in my wordpress landing page as described in Journaya. I am facing issue to save leadid token in my submissions. I inspected the hidden input it is running fine and generating input value dynamically but its not saving the value in entries of elementor form. This Highlighted part is not saving in submissions.
I am facing issue to save leadid token in my submissions. I inspected the hidden input it is running fine and generating input value dynamically but its not saving the value in entries of elementor form. This Highlighted part is not saving in submissions.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
